# IOS Swift 3 Universal Automatic layout

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a game in SpriteKit and I present a few images at certain coordinates.

However when I run the game on an iPad vs an iPhone, etc, the images are in different locations and may be cut off due to the locations not being a part of that device.

How can I make it so it is the same layout on any iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scaleMode`

scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill

also resize the scene in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let skView = self.view as SKView
    if let scene = skView.scene {
        if scene.size != self.view.bounds.size {
            scene.size = self.view.bounds.size
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can set the locations and sizes based on the device programmatically in your GameViewController

for example:

```
spriteNode.size = CGSize(height: size.height * 0.5, width: size.height * 0.5)
```

You can also check this library [SpriteKitAutoLayout](https://github.com/mgrebenets/SpriteKitAutoLayout)

Comment: Thanks!  Helped alot